# gurobi constraint to prevent repeated solution

Tags: python, gurobi, mixed-integer-programming

i want to create multiple optimal solutions from my gurobi optimization MIP model but not using the PoolMode. instead, i have a model that creates the optimal NBA DFS lineup. one of my constraints makes sure that a player isnt in more than 1/3 of all solutions. i am trying to add another constraint that checks if the current solution already exists in another list called `created_lineups`. how do i do that?

i am trying this:
`m.addConstrs((set([x for x in player_pos_map if y[x].X == 1]) != set(i) for i in created_lineups), name='unique_lineup')`

but i get the error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MB6dt.png)

Comment: Please don't share images, post the code / error instead, with the proper formatting

Answer (score 0):

You are complaining that `set( ... )` is not hashable.

Trivially, we could use the expression `tuple(sorted(set( ... )))`

But you might want to examine how your higher level goals work into that.